# Schunk_svh_driver:How to use channel_feedback in gui

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
can you help me to use the topic channel_feedback() in rqt-rviz?
Can I use this topic to read values of current/effort and so adjourn position in the topic channel_target?
Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208173/schunk_svh_driver:how-to-use-channel_feedback-in-gui/) by [Alba](https://answers.ros.org/users/22228/alba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2015-04-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, it seemed so.

have you read 5.2 standalone usage ?

If you want to check out that everything is working or just want to move the hand into any position you can use the package as standalone with sliders.......the hand is ready and fingers can be moved by using the Joint State publisher gui that has come up.

this joint-state-publisher is using then the topic channel_target to setup a new position of a finger

---

Originally posted by [inflo](https://answers.ros.org/users/4215/inflo/) with karma: 406 on 2015-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1